# Lost in google api using OAuth2 to get user's calendars events

Tags: reactjs, google-api

I'm trying to fetch user's calendars events into my full callendar component. I started with a public calendar using classic api key and it works but now i want to fetch user's related datas through OAuth2 but i can't figure out how to properly make the auth chain.

I've seen that "google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient()" give me the access token in order to fetch user's calendars list. It opens the google login iFrame properly but only if I call  "google.accounts.id.initialize()" first. Seem's a bit disturbing because it makes me open 2 times the login iFrame when i see many vids doing it in one login.

Secondly, fetching "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList" throw error 401 with a right "Bearer <access_token>" header in the payload. So both access tokens i get from initialize and initTokenClient are wrong ?? (i tried both)

I think i just don't understand properly the login/auth consent fetch chain and everything i find on the web seem's to be deprecated (old gapi way) or vary a lot from tutorials to tutorials.

Any suggestions to reuse my code or restart from scratch with proper method?

Always losing time trying to understand api docs when the final component (calendar) is working.

Thanks for your time reading me :)

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "../api/axios";

import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

// import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";  
// import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"; 
// import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid"
// import frLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/fr'
// import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar'

import BrowserSidenav from "../components/BrowserSidenav.jsx"; 

const Agenda = (props) => {
    const [googleUser, setGoogleUser] = useState({});
    const [googleUserAccessToken, setGoogleUserAccessToken] = useState("");

    //FUNCS
    function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
        console.log(response.credential)

        document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden = true;
        setGoogleUser(jwt_decode(response.credential));

        const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: 'MY CLIENT ID',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
            prompt: '',
            callback: (response) => {
                setGoogleUserAccessToken(response.access_token);
            },
        });

        client.requestAccessToken();
    }

    function handleSignOut(e) {
        setGoogleUser({})
        document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden = false;
    }

    //EFFECTS
    useEffect(() => {
        /* global google */
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "MY CLIENT ID",
            callback: handleCallbackResponse,
        });

        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
        )
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCalendarDatas = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList",
                    {
                        headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer " + googleUserAccessToken},
                    }
                );
                console.log(response)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        {googleUserAccessToken !== "" && getCalendarDatas();}
    }, [googleUserAccessToken])

    return (
        <>
            <BrowserSidenav />
            <div className="browser-content page-clients">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header className="contacts-list-header" style={{overflow: "hidden"}}>
                        <h2>Agenda</h2>
                        <div id="signInDiv" style={{marginLeft: "auto"}}></div>
                        { Object.keys(googleUser).length !== 0 &&
                            <Button variant="sub" onClick={(e) => handleSignOut(e)} style={{marginLeft: "auto"}}>Se déconnecter</Button>
                        }
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        {/* { googleUserAccessToken !== "" &&
                            // <div className="fullcalendar-container">
                            //     <FullCalendar
                            //         headerToolbar={{
                            //             left: 'prev,next today',
                            //             center: 'title',
                            //             right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                            //         }}
                            //         initialView="dayGridMonth"
                            //         locale={frLocale}
                            //         plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
                            //         
                            //         eventSources={[
                            //             { ????? }
                            //         ]}
                            //     />
                            // </div>
                        } */}
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Agenda;
```